# An issue making addition through models.py making a simple calculation

Tags: python, html, css, django, rendering

Hello guys im practicing on django by now developping a simple expense tracker for a main project expample: Buying a flippable car for X amount and adding all the other expenses to get a single total.

**my operation is mainly done in my model.py**

```
models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Expenses(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='expenses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    
    def get_total_project_amount(self):
        return self.amount  + self.project.amount
```

What i wanna do is adding the main project and all the expenses togheter, but im not using the proper way, when i render the resuld it renders like this:

main project: 50$
expenses added from a model form : 2(new)
expense: 13(new)
expense: 25(new)

the total is: 52
total: 63
total: 75

I wanna render the main project and all the expenses to get a single result, something like 50+2+13+25
total : 90$ total amount soent to fix the car.

Anyone that understand addition lojic help please and thank you

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum upt the expenses with:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    # …
    
    @property    
    def total_amount(self):
        subtotal = self.expenses.aggregate(
            subtotal=Sum('amount')
        )['subtotal'] or 0
        return self.amount + subtotal
```

You can thus determine the total cost for a `Project` object `myproject` with:

```
myproject.total_amount
```

this will thus sum up the `amount` plus the sum of all the *related* `Expenses`.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Expense` instead of <s>`Expenses`</s>.

---

> **Note**: When you make calculations with money, it is better to use a [**`DecimalField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DecimalField),
> not a [**`FloatField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FloatField). Floats can generate rounding errors when you perform calculations.
> You can also use [**`django-money`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django-money/django-money/) to specify a `MoneyField`. This has also specifies a currency, and can convert money to a different
> currency.